# Expression<Func<T, bool>> with It.IsAny always return true

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, moq, expression-trees

I'm trying to create a generic testclass to test my generic controllers. Everything is working fine except this:
I have a method like this:

```
private T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
```

I'm trying to setup the test like so:

```
var Guids = new[] { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() };
var items = Guids.Select(x => new T {Id = x});
var mock = new Mock<IRepository<T>>();
mock.Setup(m => m.GetSingle(
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>()))
   .Returns(new T());
```

And execute the test like this:

```
var value = Repository.GetSingle(x=> x.Id == Guid.NewGuid());
```

This *always* return a new T.

Is my setup wrong?

Comment: What is it that you're testing? It seems to me you want to mock to actually implement the repository lookup logic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're instructing Moq to return the same exact instance (in this case, `new T()`), any time `GetSingle` is invoked, regardless of the expression provided. What you actually want is for it to invoke that expression against `items`:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.GetSingle(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>()))
   .Returns<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>(expression => items.AsQueryable().Single(expression));
```

Comment: Thanks Hacked! I've been working on this for a while now, and couldnt get it to work properly. I'm quite new to this, thanks for helping me improve!

Comment: `Single()` does do what is meant and it has [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534800.aspx) that takes exactly that argument. And it's probably better, because it will throw if there is more than one matching item.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake on the predicate overload.